# MySQL InnoDB: Difference Between `FOR SHARE` and `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`

Tags: mysql

What is the difference of the following two sql:
`select * from user where id = 1 for share`
`select * from user where id = 1 lock in share mode`
Are they have the same effect that lock a row with shared lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

> `FOR SHARE` and `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` set shared locks that permit other transactions to read the examined rows but not to update or delete them. **`FOR SHARE` and `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` are equivalent.** However, `FOR SHARE`, like `FOR UPDATE`, supports `NOWAIT`, `SKIP LOCKED`, and `OF tbl_name` options. `FOR SHARE` is a replacement for `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`, but `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` remains available for backward compatibility.